# HDD Guardian reports ATA error

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart, ata

I have just ran HDD Guardian on my Hitachi Travelstar 7K1000 hard drive (2.5, 7200rpm) and noticed that the drive reported an ATA error.

The error occurred 37 hours (of disk power-on time) ago, and it has been working fine since then. I hadn't even realised, as I usually use CrystalDiskInfo, and it reported everything was OK.

The errors are ICRC: Interface Cyclic Redundancy Code error
and ABRT: command Aborted.

You can see the details here:

[image]

[image]

All the S.M.A.R.T. information is OK, and nothing strange or alarming has happened. There are no more ATA errors either.

The drive is new (it is on an MSI laptop that's a week old) and hasn't been used much (OS is in an SSD). Is there anything I should be worried about with the drive? What could have been the cause of such an error, and what does this error imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that there was a problem communicating with the drive over the SATA cable.  If it was happening a lot then you should replace the cable, but since it only happened once, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

New drive: Bould be compatible issue. Is your drive set for AHCI (Advanced Host Controller Interface)? If your going to switch modes, some windows modification maybe needed. Study up before changing mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Drive is in AHCI mode, but as it is a laptop, there is little else I can change. I think I'll do what @psusi said, and ignore it since it only happened once

Comment: Yea, though keep your stuff backed up. I would consider it unreliable, unless you figure out how/why it happen.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)